# How does the `randoms` function in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell

I'm following the [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com) book to learn Haskell, and I am having trouble understanding the `randoms` function. The book defines the function as:

```
randoms' :: (RandomGen g, Random a) => g -> [a]  
randoms' gen = let (value, newGen) = random gen in value:randoms' newGen
```

Now the way I see this function is that it calls itself recursively and appends the return value to the list `value`. What I don't understand is how the function returns because every time it just calls itself with a new random seed!

Comment: No, because of laziness, the tail is *not* evaluated until you need it.

Comment: Can't remember that function specifically, but if it creates a lazy infinite list of random numbers, you can just `take` from the infinite list to get a few of the elements. Note the function won't evaluate all at once; it only produces values as needed. Look at the `repeat` function to see another example of that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But doesn't the function need to return the control flow to the caller somewhere?

Comment: @1-_- You're thinking too strictly. Do you know what Python generators are by chance?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I just looked them up, cleared my confusion. Please add your comments as an answer.

Comment: @1-_- OK, good. I was just going to say that when working with infinite lists, you can think of it at though the values are being `yield`ed one at a time instead of the entire list being returned at once. I'd strongly recommend looking deeper into, and getting used to laziness, as Haskell makes extensive use of it.

Comment: @1-_- I don't know if I could write a good explanation, as it's been awhile since I've used Haskell, and it's a difficult topic to dive into. That's just the best comparison of could think of that might help shift your perspective.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes it did help. You can just write what you wrote about Python's generators in the comment.

Comment: Haskell functions *don't* return. Function returning is simply *not a thing* in Haskell. Saying the function never returns is as meaningful as saying the function never eats cheese.

Comment: @immibis When I said "returns" I was actually talking about the control flow and return value being returned to the caller.

Comment: @1-_- And when I said "eats cheese" I was actually talking about ingesting coagulated bovine lactation. What's your point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a crude comparison, instead of trying to think of how an infinite list could be returned, consider how a Python generator is capable of "returning" an infinite list:  by `yield`ing one element at a time, as they're required.

The entire list isn't returned at once. Each element is evaluated as it's needed, and the function only recurses as it needs to.

Note, I'm not claiming Haskell's laziness works the same way as Python's generators, but it may be a helpful comparison to keep in mind when thinking about functions like these.

See the other answer to get an explanation of why this is happening.

Comment: A related, useful insight for me was that lists in Haskell aren’t great when used as *data* structures (if you want to store a sequence of elements, a `Vector` or something is probably better) but they’re excellent *control* structures, behaving more or less like (memoised) iterators & generators in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

I think the confusing part might be the use of `:` in the return value.

```
value:randoms' newGen
```

This is a list, with the first item of `value`, and the rest of the list is what is returned by the recursive call to `randoms' newGen`.

> What I don't understand is how the function returns because every time it just calls itself with a new random seed!

Because of laziness, it will only call itself if you try to access the second (or later) item of the returned list. This list isn't, and couldn't be in memory, at once. Lists in Haskell are more like recipes... until you try to access an element, Haskell doesn't try to work out what it is.